# C - How do I return a word with all even bits set to 1 and all odd bits set to 0?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I can only use these operators ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

This is the code that I have so far but I can't figure out how to get it to work

```
int setEvenBitsToOne(){
    int byte = 0x55;
    int word = byte | byte << 8;
    return word | word << 16;
}
```

Comment: Is `return 0x55555555` too easy?

Comment: you have no input in your routine. You may as well return a constant...

Comment: If you want to return the a 16 bit(commonly called a "word") binary number 1010 1010 1010 1010 , then  you can convert that binary number to hex and just write `return 0x____;` If you mean a 32 bit integer, the cocept is the same - convert 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 1010 to hex. More generally, you should explain what is not working, not just tell us "I can't figure out how to get it to work".  What doesn't work in your code ? What happens when you run it ? What did you expect to happen ?

Comment: I have a strange deja-vue. That same question was asked some days/weeks before.

Comment: @nos: 16 bits is not "commonly called a word". That is completely platform-dependent.

Comment: If `int` has only 16 bits, your code invokes undefined behaviour. Same if you change the sign. Use unsigned **fixed width** integers.

Comment: @DietrichEpp How about for `int setEvenBitsToOne() { return 0x5555555555555555 & INT_MAX; }`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of an integer is known, you can hard code it.

```
int alternatingBits() {
    switch( sizeof(int) ) {
        case 2:
            return 0x5555;
        case 4:
            return 0x55555555;
        case 8:
            return 0x5555555555555555;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unknown int size: %zu\n", sizeof(int));
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

`sizeof(int)` is a constant, so the compiler will optimize all that into a constant.

But I'm assuming this is an exercise in bit twiddling. First thing is we need is to only change the even bits. This can be done by having a bitmask of 1, adding it to the number, shifting the mask over 2 places, and adding again.

```
// C doesn't have a way to represent literal binary numbers,
// so I'm using the Perl convention.
num += 0b000001
num += 0b000100
num += 0b010000
...and so on...
```

The bitmask is moved with `mask = mask << 2`.

We also need to know when to stop. Since we're pushing up against the limits of integer size, we don't want to be doing anything like `mask < INT_MAX` because `mask = mask << 2` will probably overflow. Instead, we can iterate through number of bits in an integer 2 at a time.

```
int alternatingBits() {
    /* Our number to start with */
    int num = 0;

    /* Our bitmask to add to the number */
    int mask = 1;

    /* The number of bits in an integer
       (to avoid clutering the for loop) */
    const int bits = sizeof(int) * 8;

    /* Step through each even bit */
    for( int i = 0; i < bits; i+=2 ) {
        /* Add the mask */
        num += mask;

        /* Shift the 1 over two bits */
        mask = mask << 2;
    }

    return num;
}
```

There's a subtle problem in this case that @Olaf mentioned in the comments. When we reach the end, `mask` will be shifted over one bit more than an integer can hold. Even though we don't use it at that point, it pokes the dragons of [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is license for the compiler to do whatever it wants.

We need to make sure that doesn't happen, it means we'll have to write our own modified `for` loop.

Also the high bit of an integer is for signedness, so we should probably make our bitmask an unsigned integer to be safe.

```
int alternatingBits() {
    int num = 0;
    unsigned int mask = 1;
    const int bits = sizeof(int) * 8;

    /* This does the same as a for loop, but lets us end before incrementing mask */
    int i = 0;
    while( 1 ) {
        num += mask;

        /* increment i and check if we're done before incrementing the mask */
        i += 2;
        if( i >= bits ) {
            break;
        }

        mask = mask << 2;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Now `mask` will not overflow, and it also doesn't have to worry about the signed bit.

Comment: `int` can have a `sizeof` 1; your calculations don't make much sense here. And typically one wnats a specific width, not whatever width `int` just happens to have. And the additions invoke undefined behaviour once they overflow, as does `mask` once the value is shifted into the sign-bit.

Comment: @Olaf Did you seriously downvote me because my exercise in bit twiddling isn't practical? Yes, it doesn't cover all possible odd sizes of integers. They will  be caught by the `default` case and can be corrected. If you want different size bits, pass `bits` in.

Comment: Your code shows bad examples and contains undefined behaviour. You unnecessarily rely on implementation details (eg. `CHAR_BIT ?? 8`), too. Sorry, but that imo justifies a DV.

Comment: @Olaf Wanna maybe show how to fix it? I honestly don't know what `CHAR_BIT` has to do with this.

Comment: @Olaf How's it look now?

Comment: @Olaf And wait a second, how can `int` have a size of 1? They have to hold −32767 to 32767. Please tell me this isn't about alternative byte sizes...

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8.  Could be 9, 16, 64, etc.  8 is the most common.  With `CHAR_BIT == 16`, `sizeof(int16_t)` --> 1.

Comment: Of course it is! Please provide a reference where the standard fixes that a byte has 8 bits. There are still architectures which have e.g. 16 bits/byte. At least you should have a static assertion which ensures `CHAR_BIT == 8`. Better write the code appropriately. (As a sidenote: using non-prototype function signatures in an obsolecent feature and should not be used. Please understand this will be read by beginners who often adopt such style. To be clear: _this_ would not justify a DV).

Comment: Some additional notes: I'd use bit-or instead of addition to make clear we work on bits. It does not mater much here, but results in explicit UB for the opposite case: set odd bits. In general using unsigned integers unless negatives are required is a good approach. Much less potential for UB. Regairding the width: in general one wants a specific bit-width, so using the fixed-width types helps avoid all this fuss with `sizeof` and `CHAR_BIT`. And I don't think that was part of the original assignment.

Comment: The last sentence might be extended to point out this has to be accounted for under other constraints (as I pointed out above). Nevertheless I removed the DV.

Comment: Look, I know it is possible for there to be alternative byte sizes. And it's good to point out where assumptions have been made, and *I really appreciate your comments about the standard*. The problem here is the cryptic way it was explained, and the downvote ("this answer is not useful") over minor, easily corrected stuff especially when nobody else even tried to answer it. "`CHAR_BIT ?? 8`" is cryptic. "You're assuming bytes are 8 bits, use CHAR_BIT to be safe" is useful. "While you don't use `mask` again, it's still UB, so do X instead" is useful. Clear critique with a correction.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT ??` is actually a typo. The `?` is next to the `=` key on german keyboard layout. It should have been `CHAR_BIT == 8` which should be very clear. I noticed it only now as you complain - maybe you should have asked about that instantly, it might ahve saved both of us a lot of typing. The DV was for providing code which can invoke UB, resp. implementatin-specific behaviour unnecessarily. And as you see, I'm not the kind of person to very well remove a DV.

Comment: ... FWIW: I have a simple version for the first snippet in mind which would not require all this at. I'm just too lazy to write an answer myself. Hint: it involves unsigned integers and a loop.